# How to access AWS EC2 instance from web browser on Linux machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

When I try to connect to my EC2 instance using web browser (Mozilla Firefox) using the third option in the connect (EC2 Instance Connect (browser-based SSH connection) ), I get the following error in the new pop-up window:

> There was a problem setting up the instance connection
>   Log in failed. If this instance has just started up, try again in a minute or two.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

- Make sure the instance was launched from `Amazon Linux 2` or `Ubuntu 16.04 or later`
- Check that the instance is in a **public subnet** (defined as having a Route Table that points to an Internet Gateway)
- Open the **Security Group** for SSH (port 22) either for the whole Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`) (which is a very poor choice for security) or from the IP address ranges for EC2 Instance Connect (See: [AWS IP Address Ranges - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html))

EC2 Instance Connect in your browser establishes a web connection to the AWS service. Then, the SSH connection is established from the AWS Service to the Amazon EC2 instance. This is why the security group needs to allow incoming connections from the IP address range associated with the EC2 Instance Connect Service (not your own IP address).

Alternative ways to connect are:

- Run an SSH client on your computer, or
- Use AWS Systems Manager Session Manager (which connects via an Agent running on the computer, so it's not 'real' SSH)

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir,
i already have allowed security group and instance is in the public subnet and instance is ubuntu 18.04, but it's still not working.

Comment: I don't mean to sound dismissive, but this stuff works well, and John Rothstein has provided an excellent answer.  If it's still not working for you, you must have missed a step.  Are you sure you have the correct rules defined in your security group?  What, exactly, does "i already have allowed security group" actually mean?

Comment: thank you sir, Yeah John's answer is excellent.  i have solved this issue by configuring ec2 instance connect.

Comment: @Manjeet What was the solution? Was there a missing step in the instructions?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thank you sir. yeah there was one small thing missing that we have to configure ec2 instance connect if we are using Ubuntu 16.04 or later ami.

Comment: Ah! Probably the username?